# How to turn off/disable cache tag programmatically

Tags: footer

When I disabled `block_html` cache tag then my code works fine.

I want to know how I can disable `block_html` programmatically in Magento for `footer.phtml` file?

Comment: Clear your cache?

Answer (score 2):

There is method inside Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

```
/**
 * Load block html from cache storage
 *
 * @return string | false
 */
protected function _loadCache()
{
    if (is_null($this->getCacheLifetime()) || !$this->_getApp()->useCache(self::CACHE_GROUP)) {
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see the block will not be loaded from cache if its lifetime is **null**

Then open Footer Block file:

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    protected $_copyright;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => false));
        $this->addCacheTag(array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG
        ));
    }
```

And all you need is put value 'null' instead of 'false'

```
$this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));
```

**Don't forget that magento strongly recommend do not edit core files.**